# Pad/Fill missing columns in CSV file (using tabs)

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have some CSV files with TAB as separator. The lines have variable amount of columns and I want to normalize that.

I need exactly say 10 columns so effectively I want to add empty column up until 10th column in case it has fewer columns.

Also I would like to loop all files in a folder and update the corresponding file and not just output or write to a new file.

I can manage to do it with commas like this:

```
awk -F, '{$10=""}1' OFS=',' file.txt
```

But when changing it to `\t` i breaks and adds too many columns:

```
awk -F, '{$10=""}1' OFS='\t' file.txt
```

Any inputs?

Comment: `awk` is overkill. Use `cut`, which use TAB as delimiter by default. To update the file you can probably use `sponge`, or write to a temp file and overwrite later. There's really not much difference.

Comment: Also, if you insist on `awk`, then `-F,` should also be changed to `-F'\t'`.

Comment: Part of your problem is that you're following the very bad habit that some people have of setting FS and OFS separately when they have the same value. Always set them together in the BEGIN section `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} ...` when they need to be the same string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have GNU awk (sometimes called `gawk`), this will make sure that you have ten columns and it won't erase tenth if it is already there:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' '{NF=10}1' file >file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

Awk users value brevity and a further simplification, as suggested by JID, is possible.  Since, under awk, `NF=10` evaluates to true, we can set `NF` to 10 at the same time that we cause the line to be printed:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'NF=10' file >file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

**MacOS:** On a Mac, the default awk is BSD but GNU awk (`gawk`) can be installed using `brew install gawk`.

Comment: You can just do `NF=10` without the one as it evauluated to the number it is set to(10) which evaluated to true.

Comment: @JID Very nice. I added your `NF=10` simplification to the answer.

Comment: In mac, use `gawk` (install from brew) instead of built-in `awk`.

Comment: @cakraww Good point.  I added information on homebrew to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /YourFolder -name "*.csv" -exec sed -i 's/$/\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t/;s/^\(\([^\t]*\t\)\{9\}[^\t]*\).*/\1/' {} \;
```

- The `find` for taking all your CSV files
- the `sed`

  - `-i` for inline editing and avoid temporary file
  - add 9 tab on each line then keep only the 10 first element (separated by 9 tab)

A version that only change line that are not compliant:

```
find /YourFolder -name "*.csv" -exec sed -i '/^\([^\t]*\t\)\{9\}[^\t]*$/ ! {
   s/$/\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t/
   s/^\(\([^\t]*\t\)\{9\}[^\t]*\).*/\1/
   }' {} \;
```

**Auto adapt column number**

```
# change the 2 occurance of "9" by the number of wanted column - 1
find /YourFolder -name "*.csv" -exec sed -i ':cycle
/^\([^\t]*\t\)\{9\}[^\t]*$/ ! {
       # optimize with number ot \t on line below
       s/$/\t/
       s/^\(\([^\t]*\t\)\{9\}[^\t]*\).*/\1/
       b cycle
       }' {} \;
```

- you can optimize your case by adding several `\t` instead of 1 per cycle (best should be the average missing column with a normal distribution)

Comment: I my real life case I need 125 columns so I think it will be a complete mess. Any way to deal with that? Thx for suggestion!

Comment: no problem for the concept itself, just use a variable with 125 tab (easy to generate) instead of direct text inside the sed and change the 9 by 124. Now in performance point of view, awk is certainly faster for that. I will add another version that auto adapt the number of column