# cat command merging two *.txt with missing columns mac osx

Tags: cat

I like to use the `cat` command to join several *.txt files under mac osx.

my first `file1.txt` looks like:

```
a;b;c;d
1;2;3;4
```

second `file2.txt`:

```
a;b
5;6
7;8
```

what I want:

```
a;b;c;d
1;2;3;4
5;6;;
7;8;;
```

my question: can I skip the header from the second file in the output file? And how is cat dealing with the missing columns? writing NaNs?

maybe this command could do it?

```
head -1 file1.txt > all.txt;
tail -n +2 -q file*.txt >> all.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the `cat` command alone will deal with removing the headers or mark any missing columns, since all it does is concatenate files. But if you know the highest possible number of columns, you can do something like this:

`cat file1.txt <( tail -n+2 file2.txt ) | gawk -F';' -v OFS=';' '{NF=4}1'`

Where NF=4 is the highest number of columns (in your example, 4).
The command above is concatenating file1.txt with a header-less version of file2.txt, using the output of a subcommand as input (operator <( ) ). You can use the <( ) as many times you want for each file you're wanting to concatenate. The final command, gawk, was adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644056/pad-fill-missing-columns-in-csv-file-using-tabs#29644272)) and it's padding out the column delimiters for you.

(note: use `brew install gawk` if gawk isn't found; Mac OS X's awk won't work)

If not having the first header doesn't bother you and you don't want to use cat, you could do:

`gawk -F';' -v OFS=';' '{NF=4}1' file*.txt | egrep -v '^a;b'`

Comment: unfortunately your suggestions are just "tailing" both files together. but i see no effect of awk.. shoudnt it write delimiters ; ?

Comment: My bad, I keep forgetting Mac OS's awk isn't gawk.
"brew install gawk"
followed by replacing 'awk' by 'gawk' in the original commands should do it.